# Ruby on Rails: Multiple polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, project-management, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

Is it possible to have a multiple polymorphic association? 
I explain better:

1. I have **different kind** of users: simple_user, society, collaborator, admin, and they are different in db fields and authorization through application.
2. Every users can **request** for something
3. A request can be for **different services**: traduction, consultance etc

I was thinking about one table for each service: Traduction, consultance in which:

```
has_one :request, :as => requestable
```

then just one table Request in which:

```
belongs_to :requestable, :polymorphic => true
```

but then is it possible to add another polymorphic association **towards user tables**?
How can I handle this relationship better? Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can define multiple polymorphic associations. They'll all use their own database columns.

Create two columns `user_type` and `user_id` in your `requests` table and define this association :

```
belongs_to :user, :polymorphic => true
```

Then you should be able to assign a `Collaborator` to a `Request` :

```
Request.create!(:user => Collaborator.first)
```